# KDE4: move window to another workspace by dragging?

Tags: kde

I'm trying to move a window to the adjacent workspace by dragging it , but when the window touches the edges , it enlarges and try to occupy the right half of the screen.

Is this behavior configurable in KDE4 ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System Settings > Workspace Behavior > Screen Edges; Switch desktop on edge: Disabled/Only When Moving Windows/Always Enabled.

KDE Userbase: http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Workspace_Behaviour

> In the Screen Edges module you can choose between certain actions to
>   be triggered when the mouse moves to one of the edges or corners of
>   the screen. Each edge, and each corner can have its own action
>   attached. You can also decide whether you want windows to be maximized
>   when you drag them to the top edge of the screen, or to be tiled when
>   you drag them to the sides of the screen. Finally you can set what
>   happens to windows when you drag them across the screen edge.

[image]